# React Comlink Web Worker blocks UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, web-worker

I am starting a long running process via Comlink. While the web worker is working, react state updates do not lead to an immediate UI update, only some seconds delayed and then suddenly all "buffered" at once.

Details:

*onStartWalkForward* is triggered by a button click.

The problem starts already with the first state update:

```
this.setState({walkForwardLog: ["Starting WFO..."]})
```

The state is immediately updated and a WFOLog Function which gets the state as a prop is immediately called, so far so good. But the UI is not immediately updated. Only 5-7 seconds later. It seems something is blocking the UI because after this 5-7 sec delay there are suddenly multiple log lines in the console telling me the WFOLog function was called multiple times during this delay.

This is the same behavior for following state updates where the writeWfoLog callback is used. I can tell because `console.log("Revieved Text: " + text)` and my log of the Log function is showing up in the console 5-6 seconds before the UI shows the same text. After the delay, as described above, multiple log lines in console log suddenly.

**Could anyone explain me why and what I could do to improve that UI behavior?**

Here is the code:

***index.js***

```
  onStartWalkForward = async(percOos100, cycleCount, selectedStartDate) => {

    let dataLoaded = await this.onLoadWFOData(selectedStartDate)

    if(dataLoaded) {      
      this.setState({walkForwardLog: ["Starting WFO..."]})

      let samples = await wfUtils.getSamplesForWfo(this.state.wfoSets, percOos100, cycleCount)

      await wfUtils.startNew(this.state.selectedStrategyIndex, 
                    this.state.exposedStrategyProperties.map(p => {return {name: p.name, range: this.state[p.name].range}}),
                    samples, 
                    this.writeWfoLog)         
    }
  }

  writeWfoLog = async(text) => {
    console.log("Revieved Text: " + text)  

    let log = this.state.walkForwardLog;        
    log.push(text)     
    this.setState({walkForwardLog: log})
  }
```

***wfUtils.js***

```
export async function startNew(selectedStrategyIndex, exposedStrategyProperties, samples, writeWfoLog) {

    const obj = new WfoWorker()

    const wfoWorker = Comlink.wrap(obj);

    for (let i = 0; i < samples.length; i++) {
        await writeWfoLog(`Running Optimization ${i+1} of ${samples.length}...` )        

        await wfoWorker.optimize(
            selectedStrategyIndex, 
            exposedStrategyProperties,
            samples[i], 
            i+1,
            samples.length
        )            

        let bestCombination = await wfoWorker.bestCombination   

        let bestCombinationText = bestCombination.split(";").map(p => Number.isInteger(p) ? parseInt(p) : parseFloat(p)).join(";");    

        await writeWfoLog("BC: " + bestCombinationText)                
    }

    await writeWfoLog("Finished WFO.")
}
```